# Измение стилей, импортированных из vue-material.scss

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, material-ui

Здравствуйте,

Я пишу на Vue.js + vue-material.scss, в один из компонентов я импортирую стили из vue-material.scss.

Моя задача: конкретно для этого компонента, немного добавить стили к стилям vue-material.scss.

Для этого, я ввел название класса из vue-material.scss, и добавил несколько своих стилей, которые НЕ перекрывают стили из vue-material.scss, а просто добавляют к существующим, т.е. все должно без проблем работать. Но нет! Мои изменения просто не добавляются к стилям vue-material.scss, что отчетливо видно в отладчике.

Буду очень благодарен за помощь!

Спасибо за уделенное время!

Comment: подозреваю что вы свои стили где-то не подключили к сборке. опишите как собираете, где подключаете.